# How to see the Javascript code line responsible on displaying element X after clicking on element Y

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, onclicklistener, firebug

I got a Wordpress website to modify.

So I have this "login" button that after it gets clicked, it display a hidden form.

I am trying to trigger this event on an other button on the same page so it will function the same.

So I have tried the Chrome listener and tracked the mouse-click event, so I do see the steps of that same event there, in a very sloppy way.

I tried using FIREBUG to track it, gives me much nicer organized information in the 'DOM' after clicking the button.

But where can I see from the DOM output where the rest of the changes that happen on the page after clicking occur? for other elements affected after the click event. where can I see the exact code line so I can understand how it's triggered?

EDIT: I tried using VISUAL EVENT - I do see a command line in the popup window, but nothing about it's location. I tried searching the command in all .js files and I cant find it.

I tested this on a different website - and I did find the command line.

What should I do in this case, where can the JS file be?

Answer (score 0):

In Firebug, clicking on an HTML element allows you to view any [events](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Events_Side_Panel) associated with it. Once you discover what function is being called with the click event you can follow along through the code to see what other functions are being called.

Firebug also allows you to place breakpoints, which is useful for debugging. The specific breakpoint you may be interested in is [Break On Attribute Change](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Break_On_...). Combine this with the login button and you should be able to figure out what all is happening with the code.